# TFS Web Access & SharePoint Portal Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, tfs, tfs-web-access

We have the same error on both our Team Web Access AND our SharePoint project portals from our TFS2010 server.

Access through Visual Studio appears to be fine.

However, anywhere a list of work items should appear in either web environment we are instead seeing

> Method not found: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.ScopedFieldDefinitionsClass Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.NodeClass.get_GlobalFieldDefinitions()'.

We are unable to create items in either web portal as well.

We have tried clearing caches on the TFS and clients then restarting TFS to no avail.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely seems like a cache issue unless you updated TFS recently. Web Access and SharePoint web parts have different cache locations.

You can find the correct cache path by looking at web.config appSettings value with key "WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot" or something like that. Please make sure you blow away the correct cache.